# Trying to dual boot install Kali Linux on Windows 10, consistent black screen once installation tries to begin

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

I’ve been a Linux user for a little while now, mostly Mint and feel as though it’s time to move on to bigger and better things. For the past day and a half, I have been trying to dual boot Kali and I can’t get it to work, I feel as though I have exhausted all options.

I do the classic partitioning, USB formatting and all that runs smoothly but for some reason whenever I go to click install a black prompt screen will pop up and it will freeze.  It has happened about 45 times now (no exaggeration).

I have tried every version of Kali, 32-bit/64-bit, read every single forum post...and I haven’t gotten anywhere. I tried modifying the grub config, editing the installer from the command line to correct the GFX settings, formatted the USB as ISO and DD, turned off secure boot, changed the boot order, enabled USB EFI boot and even turned off firewalls (because why not), tried initiating installer from windows then booting yet nothing works. The worst part about it is that Kali will boot fine in live mode.  So I don’t understand how it can be a GFX issue, seems like my hardware matches the Kali OS.

If anyone can shed some light on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Specifications:

- Lenovo yoga 920 (3840x2160)
- GFX: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U (16GB RAM)
- Processor Speed: 1992 MHz
- OS: Windows 10
- BIOS Mode: UEFI

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The specifics of this question aside, Kali Linux is a niche Linux distro, which you may be using with the full knowledge of what it is and for particular reasons- if so, please disregard this comment! If not, I would strongly recommend reading [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) over on Unix & Linux StackExchange. **It could save you a lot of time and hassle** :)

Comment: How is Kali *bigger and better* than Mint?

Comment: @simlev it was a figure of speech...